# Spread operator equivalent of Object assign

Tags: javascript

What would be the equivalent of merging these objects to a spread operator? I wanna use spread instead of assign in my redux app.

`return Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent would be:

```
return { ..obj1, ...obj2 };
```

However this won't work without transpiling (by babel for example), as object rest spread is a stage-3 recommendation, and not supported by current browsers. If you use babel, you'll have to use the [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) babel plugin or the [babel stage-3 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/).

Comment: so in this case when i update a property inside my object it would be return `{...obj1, obj1property: {...obj1.obj1property, ...obj2 }` ?

Comment: @NinaScholz - You'll have to transpile it before it works (stage-3 recommendation).

Comment: @Jan it would be something like `{ prop1: obj1.prop1, prop2: obj1.prop2, prop2: obj2.prop2 }`, which will translate in the end to this `{ prop1: obj1.prop1, prop2: obj2.prop2 }` as prop2 from obj1 will be replaced by obj2 prop2.

Comment: right. what I meant is merge the 2nd object to a property of the 1st object which is also an object (the 1st obj property). so this is still correct? `{...obj1, obj1property: {...obj1.obj1property, ...obj2 } }`

Comment: @Jan - indeed. If you want to update a property, which is also an object, you'll spread the property, and the update object, and assign the result to the original object property,

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

> Note: Typically the spread operators in ES6 goes one level deep while
>   copying an array. Therefore, they are unsuitable for copying
>   multidimensional arrays. It's the same case with Object.assign and
>   Object spread operators. Look at the example below for a better
>   understanding.

This means that the spread is made in anew object, so no need to pass an empty object as is `Object.assign`. Hence you can just do:

```
return {...obj1, ...obj2}
```

---

As an additional note, here is how babel transpiles the spread operator:

`const a = {...obj1, ...obj2}`

becomes:

```
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var a = _extends({}, obj1, obj2);
```

[See for yourself](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20%7B...obj1%2C%20...obj2%7D)

Comment: @NinaScholz This is an ES6 syntax, you need to use a Precompiler such as babel. Does it fail with it?